# gmrun completion setting

Tags: xfce, autocomplete

I am using *gmrun* unter XFCE to start applications through Alt+F2 shortcut. I switched on the completion (TabTimeout = 1) which I find comfortable. As *gmrun* "simulates" tab press in this case, application name is completed as soon as it is single possible (e.g. typing "libr" is enough to figure out I want to start "libreoffice") and cursor is moved to the end of the line. If one continues typing, something like "libreoffice**eoff**" could be the outcome, which is really annoying.

Is there a possibility to set up *gmrun* the way the completion is still working, but cursor does not jump to the end of the line, but 'overtype' mode is enabled (like it was the case for Gnome2)? If not, are there some alternatives, which are able to do like that?